# Is there a way to use \cref along with xepersian package

Tags: cleveref, xepersian

Is there a way to make `\Cref` command work along with xepersian package. For example, in the following code the name of the theorem is not shown by `\cref`; just the number is shown just like `\ref`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{cleveref}      
\usepackage{xepersian}
\newtheorem{theorem}{قضیه}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}\label{ss}
مم
\end{theorem}
طبق
\cref{ss}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should (a) load `cleveref` *after* all other packages are loaded (but prior to the `\newtheorem{theorem}{قضیه}` instruction) and (b) provide a suitable `\crefname{theorem}{<singular form>}{<plural form>}` instruction. I'm afraid I am utterly illiterate in Farsi and hence can't provide further pointers. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the below structure for changing `and`:

```
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{\,و\,}
```

And also You have to use the below structure for changing  `to`:

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{\,تا\,}
```

And also You have to use the below structure for define theorem (theorems) and notice (notices):

```
\crefname{thmx}{‌قضیه‌ی}{‌قضیه‌ها‌ی}
\crefname{thmy}{‌توجه}{توجه‌های}
```

Please see the following structures:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagebackref=false,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=magenta]{hyperref}   
\usepackage{cleveref} 
\usepackage[logo=on,fontsize={14,18},%
inlinemathdigits=persian,%
displaymathdigits=persian%
]{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=1.1]{XB Niloofar}
\settextdigitfont[Scale=1.1]{Yas}
\setmathdigitfont[Scale=1]{PGaramond}
\makeatletter
\newtheorem{thmx}{قضیه}
\renewcommand{\thethmx}{\thechapter \@SepMark\arabic{thmx}} 
\newtheorem{thmy}{توجه}\renewcommand{\thethmy}{\thechapter\@SepMark\arabic{thmy}}
\makeatother
\crefname{thmx}{‌قضیه‌ی}{‌قضیه‌ها‌ی}
\crefname{thmy}{‌توجه}{توجه‌های}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{\,تا\,}
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{\,و\,}
\begin{document}

\chapter{یک}
\section{اولی}
\begin{thmx}\label{ss}\normalfont
اگر داشته ‌باشیم
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
آنگاه
$\angle C=90^\circ$
\end{thmx}
\section{دومی}
\begin{thmx}\label{sd}
اگر داشته ‌باشیم
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
آنگاه
$\angle C=90^\circ$
\end{thmx}
\begin{thmx}\label{sy}
اگر داشته ‌باشیم
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
آنگاه
$\angle C=90^\circ$
\end{thmx}
\begin{thmy}\label{sr}
اگر داشته ‌باشیم
$\angle C=90^\circ$
آنگاه
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
\end{thmy}
\begin{thmy}\label{sk}
اگر داشته ‌باشیم
$\angle C=90^\circ$
آنگاه
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
\end{thmy}
طبق
\cref{ss}
داریم:\\
طبق
\cref{ss,sd}
داریم:\\
یا طبق 
\cref{ss,sd,sy}
داریم:\\
طبق
\cref{sr}
داریم:\\
یا طبق 
\cref{sr,sk}
داریم:\\
\end{document}

You will have this output:
```

[image]

Good luck.